# python BeautifulSoup get select.value not text

Tags: python, html, select, beautifulsoup

```html
<select>
  <option value="0">2002/12</option>
  <option value="1">2003/12</option>
  <option value="2">2004/12</option>
  <option value="3">2005/12</option>
  <option value="4">2006/12</option>
  <option value="5" selected>2007/12</option>
</select>
```

with this code, I need value as `'0'` not text as `'2002/12'`

I tried a lot of BS4 options, `.stripped_strings`, `.strip()`, `.contents`, `get()`, etc.

How I can get values not text?

Comment: was my answer not helpful? You accepted then unaccepted again, anything you need added?

Comment: @MartijnPieters no, it's super fine. just for error. :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You want the `value` *attribute*; access [tag attributes](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) using mapping syntax:

```
option['value']
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <select>
...   <option value="0">2002/12</option>
...   <option value="1">2003/12</option>
...   <option value="2">2004/12</option>
...   <option value="3">2005/12</option>
...   <option value="4">2006/12</option>
...   <option value="5" selected>2007/12</option>
... </select>
... ''')
>>> for option in soup.find_all('option'):
...     print 'value: {}, text: {}'.format(option['value'], option.text)
... 
value: 0, text: 2002/12
value: 1, text: 2003/12
value: 2, text: 2004/12
value: 3, text: 2005/12
value: 4, text: 2006/12
value: 5, text: 2007/12
```

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> doc = """
... <select>
...   <option value="0">2002/12</option>
...   <option value="1">2003/12</option>
...   <option value="2">2004/12</option>
...   <option value="3">2005/12</option>
...   <option value="4">2006/12</option>
...   <option value="5" selected>2007/12</option>
... </select>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(doc)
>>> list = soup.findAll('option')
>>> for l in list:
...   print l['value']
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
>>>
```