# find function returns true when false

Tags: python

I am loading the source code of a web page as a string and then want to search that string for a specific phrase.

This is what I have so far:

```
from urllib import request
r = request.urlopen("http://www.dsfire.gov.uk/News/Newsdesk/IncidentsPast7days.cfm?    siteCategoryId=3&T1ID=26&T2ID=35")
bytecode = r.read()
htmlstr = bytecode.decode() #htmlstr is now source code for page

if htmlstr.find("Todays Incidents of Interest (0)")
    print("no incidents today")
```

I want to see if there have been any incidents today - if there haven't, there is no need to continue. I have waited until I know the number of incidents is greater than `0` (by going to the site and manually monitoring) but I still get it found; what am I doing wrong?

Or is there a way of grabbing that phrase and seeing what the number is in the brackets? This might be useful, as I will set up a loop later based on that number.

Comment: We need more informations : What's the language ? Some variable types are missing... tell us more

Comment: You should use an HTML parser (BeautifulSoup is one of Python's most popular).

Comment: sorry its Python i thought i'd put that, there is a lot missing from the code as i'm just starting. Basically i'm making an mobile app that will load up incidents from the page i've included in the post for particular fire stations, for example the user will have a drop down list with all fire stations in devon and somerset and they pic theirs, the app searches through the links on the newsdesk and displays any incidents with that station

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`string.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) returns -1 on failure, not false.

Comment: You were wondering why your conditional isn't working. I'm letting you know that when the string isn't found (right now for example), your `find()` call is returning `-1`. Which isn't a false value. So your call should be either `if htmlstr.find("Todays Incidents of Interest (0)") != -1:` or `if "Todays Incidents of Interest (0)" in htmlstr:`

Comment: @Raif this answers your direct question - your real issue appears to be something else completely though... I'd suggest using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of the stdlib for your retrieving data (automatically handles decoding for you, and has a much nicer interface) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the elements you want from the `select` list... You'll end up with 2/3 lines of code in total :) (minus imports)

Comment: Thanks @Jon, I will look into it as it sounds much better to have only three lines of code! is beautifulsoup a library i can import? i saw it had to be installed when i did a quick search

Comment: @Raif yes... you'd need to install both requests and beautifulsoup4 (using pip/easy_install)

Comment: I have installed it was easy thanks! can you point me to the code you mentioned? or a tutorial i can go through? thanks again!

Comment: Thanks I'm looking into finding the div id="CollapsiblePanel1" after installing using pip  my python shell is saying >>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup' any ideas?

Comment: @Raif sorry - you didn't at me, so I didn't see your comments... look at a post like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392466/python-beautifulsoup-get-select-value-not-text/19392607#19392607) - have a play with it, and if you get stuck, then feel free to post your attempted code and any issues as another question on SO. In the mean time, may I suggest you accept Bill's answer as he has actually answered the question you asked (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/204922) for why that's a good thing for the community)

Comment: @JonClements sorry and thanks I found that i had to import from bs4 lol so that was 1 down, also i have used "webpage = request.urlopen("http://www.dsfire.gov.uk/News/Newsdesk/IncidentsPast7days.cfm?siteCategoryId=3&T1ID=26&T2ID=35")
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
>>> list = soup.find(id="CollapsiblePanel1")" and this has given me all the links in that div so now i should be able to search for the number within list as well as all the links! you're a beaut for putting me onto this!