# How to fix the find() in python as it is also returning a true condition for a sub string not present?

Tags: python

Alright, the question here is to print out the plural form of a given noun, given the input as a noun and an integer.

If the integer is 1 or -1, print out the singular form, else print out the plural form of given noun.

The `find()` function to check if a substring is present in a string or not is returning true even if the condition is false, resulting in an erroneous output.

I have already tried checking for the characters individually but that does not look like a really smart way of solving the problem.

Here's my code:

```
def singularPlural(String1, String2):
   if String2.isnumeric():
    if(int(String2)==-1 or int(String2)==1):
        print(String1)
    else:
        if(String1[-1] == 'o' or String1[-1] == 's' or String1[-1] == 'x' 
           or String1[-1] == 'z' or String1.find("ch", len(String1)-3, len(String1))):   #My mistake is probably here.
            print(String1 + "es")
        elif(String1[-1] == 'y'):
            print(String1[:-1:]+"ies")
        elif(String1.find("um", len(String1)-3)):
            printf(String1[:-2:]+"a")
        else:
            print(String1 + "s")
   else:
    if String1 in String2:
        print("Singular : {}".format(String1))
        print("Plural : {}".format(String2))
    elif String2 in String1:
        print("Singular : {}".format(String2))
        print("Plural : {}".format(String1))
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
def main():
Str1 = input("Enter a word: ")
Str2 = input("Enter a word or a number: ")
singularPlural(Str1, Str2)
   if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

> Input 1:
>
> Arch, 2
>
> Input 2
>
> Baby, 2

> Expected Output 1: Arches
>
> Expected Output 2 : Babies
>
> Actual Output 1 : Arches
>
> Actual Output 2 : Babyes << fail

Comment: Your whole code would be better served in terms of maintainability and clarity if you use dictionaries instead of `if elif` all the way. The current problem you have demonstrates how difficult it is to debug and comprehend the control flow. I highly recommend you think through your logic flow carefully and draw it out, and then fit it into a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> string.find() returns -1 on failure, not false.
>    [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26530489/6212957)

so you could either check for validation where `find()` returns a value > 0
`String1.find("ch", len(String1)-3, len(String1)) > 0):`

or you could simply use slicing to get the last two characters

```
if((String1[-1] in ('o','s','x','z')) or String1[-2:] == "ch"):
    print(String1 + "es")
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` returns -1, if sub string search fails.
You need to check for following.

 `String1.find("ch", len(String1)-3, len(String1))) != -1`

Answer (score 1):

The `find()` method returns the *lowest index* of the substring if it is found. If it is not found then it returns `-1`.
Your code should be:

```
if(String1[-1] == 'o' or String1[-1] == 's' or String1[-1] == 'x' 
or String1[-1] == 'z' or String1.find("ch", len(String1)-3, len(String1)) != -1):   
            print(String1 + "es")
```